# Hacer un scatter sobre una gráfica de líneas en python con pandas y matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Tengo un programa en Python que lee un dataframe y desde este hace una gráfica en línea con su información, estoy intentando hacer un scatter sobre esa misma gráfica pero con otro dataframe, pero mis intentos han fracasado y tuve que reintentar la gráfica desde cero, funciona mejor pero no se me ocurre una manera de hacer lo que quiero. Lo que quiero obtener es los datos del 2015 en el dataframey que se esparzan de manera scatter los records TMIN y TMAX sobre la misma gráfica, estos mismos los guardé en el dataframe TMIN2015. Adjuntaré el código y cómo el archivo csv se ve

```
    
    TMIN2015 = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv', sep=r'\s*,\s*',
                           header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python')
    TMIN2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(TMIN2015['Date'])
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015[(TMIN2015['Date'] > '2015-01-01') & (TMIN2015['Date'] < '2015-12-31')]
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015.sort_values(by="Date")
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].agg([('TMIN','min'), ('TMAX','max')])
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015.reset_index()
    #TMIN2015 = TMIN2015[['Date','TMIN','TMAX']]
    
    
    return plt.show()

leaflet_plot_stations(400,'fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89')
```

Un ejemplo de cómo se ve la tabla originalmente, sin las modificaciones en el código:

|  | ID | Date | Element | Data_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USW00094889 | 2014-11-12 | TMAX | 22 |
| 1 | USC00208972 | 2009-04-29 | TMIN | 56 |
| 2 | USC00200032 | 2008-05-26 | TMAX | 278 |

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Si deseas hacer un `scatter` sobre gráficas de líneas puedes simplemente agregar `scatter()` a la gráfica que ya tienes

En algunas de tus preguntas pasadas ya había explicado que es importante utilizar variables para trabajar con tus gráficas más fácilmente, voy a reutilizar el código que puse en una de tus preguntas anteriores (Hacer gris el área entre dos líneas)

En este caso tenemos 2 líneas con escalas diferentes, para cada gráfica utilizo una variable (`ax1` y `ax2`)

Para agregar el `scatter` a la gráfica 1 (TMIN) puedes hacer esto `ax1.scatter(df['Date'], y1, color='r')`. Puedes sustituir los valores para X (En este ejemplo `df['Date']`) y para Y (En este ejemplo `y1` que es `df['TMIN']`) con la información que desees mostrar

Ejemplo funcionando:

```
ax1 = df.plot(x ='Date', y='TMIN', kind = 'line')
ax2 = df.plot(x ='Date', y='TMAX',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)

y1 = df['TMIN']
y2 = df['TMAX']

ny = ((y2-np.min(y2))/(np.max(y2)-np.min(y2)))*(np.max(y1)-np.min(y1))+np.min(y1)

ax1.fill_between(df['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1<=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
ax1.fill_between(df['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1>=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Temperature Frequency')
plt.title('Record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014')

ax1.scatter(df['Date'], y1, color='r')
ax2.scatter(df['Date'], y2, color='g')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Buen día, gracias por responder pero este método no me fue de todo útil antes, intenté usarlo  y el fill_between me genera un error. Cabe mencionar que el scatter que quiero usar sobre el dataframe TMIN me causa un KeyError con "Date" como referencia, es por eso que usé otro método, el del código adjuntado, como mencioné es el único que me está funcionando. El método que sugieres me causa muchos más errores de los que debería de, créeme que digo que lo he intentado y realmente no sé por qué no me funciona. Aún así muchas gracias, intentaré en un momento tu código para ver si llega a funcionar

Comment: El problema es que yo estoy trabajando con datos simulados (Los que has puesto en tus preguntas) y al probar a mi no me da ningún error, por eso pongo la respuesta, si pudieras compartir más información sobre los datos reales sería mejor. En otra de tus preguntas el problema `isfinite` por lo regular se debe al tipo de variable que se utiliza, entonces sabiendo el tipo de variable se puede corregir y este resultado te funcionaría sin problemas

Comment: Gracias por responder, me gustaría compartir el csv completo pero desafortunadamente es privado, por lo cuál otorgo poca información. El problema principal en ese código es al momento de querer hacer un scatter con el dataframe TMIN2015, que divide la información con el año 2015, el cuál me genera dicho error KeyError: Date. El error isinfinite recuerdo solucionarlo convirtiendo a np.datetime, realmente no estoy seguro pero de todas formas opté por la solución que se ve en la pregunta ya que logró facilitarme el trabajo. De igual manera intentaré tu solución, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por el momento mi único problema es saber cómo hacer un scatter dentro del contexto mencionado, entonces intentaré cualquier solución posible.

Comment: Como nota adicional, pregunté en otro foro sobre el problema de KeyError y curiosamente no tienen idea de qué podría ser el error. Si encuentro una solución la publicaré ASAP. Gracias a todos por su paciencia y tiempo.

Comment: Intenta agregar `plt.scatter(TMIN2015['Date'], TMIN2015['TMIN'], color='g')` justo antes de `return plt.show()` Desconozco lo que esté dentro de `TMIN2015` pero si tus columnas aún se llaman `Date` (Para el eje X) y `TMIN`  (Para el eje Y) debería funcionar. Si te sirve dime y edito la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, me imprime el error `invalid type promotion`, ¿Sabes qué significa? No sé si tenga que ver porque la columna `Date` son fechas.

Comment: Lo pude solucionar con las siguientes líneas de código:     `dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in TMIN2015['Date']]`
    
    `plt.scatter(dates, TMIN2015['TMIN'], color='g')`  Actualizaré la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Pude encontrar una solución:

Con el mismo código que adjunté en la pregunta, incluyendo estas dos líneas al final se resuelve el problema:

```
dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in TMIN2015['Date']]

plt.scatter(dates, TMIN2015['TMIN'], color='green')
plt.scatter(dates, TMIN2015['TMAX'], color='red')
```

La variable dates convierte los valores a pd.to_datetime, lo cuál lo hace más fácil de leer para un scatter, en donde es necesario.